# How to make options input selected by user, stay the same after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Hi I am trying to use local storage to save options data. As you can see in the code snippet there are options given. Suppose I select different options such as under Genre I click Action and so on. But when I refresh the page they change back to what they were originally. And this is what I dont want to happen.

This is my code for the `localStorage`

```js
    $('#search').on('click', function(){

    $('input[type="button"]').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
       localStorage.setItem(id, value);

    });     
});
```

```css
.selects-container {
display: inline-block;

}

.selects-container select {
margin: 0;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
width: 130px;
padding-left: 10px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-appearance: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 40px;
color: #a2a2a2;
font-size: .9em;
font-weight: normal;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#282828;
border: 0;
}

#browsepagebutton {
background: #6ac045;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
display:inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
height: 42px;
font-size: 16px;
position: relative;
width: 130px;
padding: 7px 0;
margin-top: 20px;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id ="searchfield">
 <div id="main-search-fields">
  <div class="selects-container">
  <p>Genre:</p>
  <select name="genre">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="action">Action</option>
  <option value="adventure">Adventure</option>
  <option value="animation">Animation</option>
</select>
</div>

  <div class="selects-container">
  <p>Rating:</p>
  <select name="rating">
  <option value="0">All</option>
  <option value="9">5</option>
  <option value="8">4</option>
  <option value="7">3</option>
  <option value="6">2</option>
  <option value="5">1</option>
  </select>
  </div>

<div class="selects-container" class="selects-container-last">
<p>Year:</p>
<select name="order_by">
<option value="0">2005</option>
<option value="9">2006</option>
<option value="8">2007</option>
<option value="7">2008</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="saveValues()" id="browsepagebutton"   value="search"  />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below will take the value of each select and set it. Then when page load it will set the values.

```
$('#browsepagebutton').on('click', function() {

  $('select').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    console.log("SetItem : " + id + " with value : " + value)
    localStorage.setItem(id, value);

  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('name');
    if (localStorage.getItem(id) !== null) {
    var value = localStorage.getItem(id);
    $(this).val(value)
    }

  });
})
```

[Here is a working example of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/35Lddn6k/1/)

Comment: This doesnt work. It works on the js fiddle but it is not working in my webpage

Comment: Do I have to activate local storage in the webbrowser?

Comment: No. But what dont work. Try the fiddle. Select some options and hit the button, then press the "Run" button again, and it should work as you want

Comment: It fixed the problem it works now but when you select the options and submit, It takes you to a movie with those options. but when you reset it goes back to the original page but it keeps those options applied.

Comment: Yes it keeps them because they are stored in the LocalStorage. if you want to reset it, you have to clear localStorage

Comment: No I meant like it is a actual search function, I want it to remember filters and also the current state of the page when you click the submit button